# pandas / numpy np.where(df['x'].str.contains('y')) vs np.where('y' in df['x'])

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, where-clause

As a newb to python and pandas, I tried:

```
df_rows = np.where('y' in df['x'])[0]
for i in df_rows:
    print df_rows.iloc[i]
```

returned no rows, but

```
df_rows = np.where(df['x'].str.contains('y'))[0]
for i in df_rows:
    print df_rows.iloc[i]
```

did work and returned rows containing `'y'` in `df['x']`.

What am I missing? Why did the first form fail? (Python 2.7)

Comment: in the first, `df['x']` is a list-like sequence and you're looking for entries that are exactly `'y'`. In the second, `df['x'].str` vectorizes string-like operations to each element in `df['x']`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas requires specific syntax for things to work. Looking for a `str` `y` using the operator [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) checks for membership of the string `y` in a pandas `Series`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['hiya', 'howdy', 'hello']})
>>> df
       x
0   hiya
1  howdy
2  hello
>>> df_rows = np.where('y' in df['x'])[0]
>>> df_rows
array([], dtype=int64)
>>> df_rows = np.where(df['x'].str.contains('y'))[0]
>>> df_rows
array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Try this and notice it returns one bool instead of three (like we might first think since there are three items in the series):

```
>>> 'y' in df['x']
False
>>> 'hiya' in df['x']
False
>>> 'hiya' in df['x'].values
True
```

You always need to think to yourself: "am I looking for items in a series, or am I looking for strings within the items within the series?"

For items in a series, use `isin`:

```
df['x'].isin(['hello'])
```

For strings within an item, use `.str.{whatever}` (or `.apply(lambda s: s)`):

```
>>> df['x'].str.contains('y')
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
>>> df['x'].apply(lambda s: 'y' in s)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

These are different operations:

- The `in` check searches if any element is equal to `'y'`. (note: For `Series` of `str`ings that may not even work correctly).
- The `.str.contains` method searches the string-representation of each element if it contains `'y'`.

The first one can only return `True` or `False` (that's because [Pythons data model says so](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) and enforces it). The second one is a normal method and returns a `Series` containing `True` or `False` (because normal methods can do what they like).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
>>> s.str.contains('a')
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
>>> s.eq('a')  # looking for an identical match
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```